# Prove that $(I-S)^{-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty S^m$ for $S(f)(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat f(n) (e^{inx}-e^{i\lambda_n x})$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us consider $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. Prove that 
$$(I-S)^{-1}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty S^m,$$ where $S(f)(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat f(n) (e^{inx}-e^{i\lambda_n x})$ verifies $\Vert S\Vert<1.$  Here $\{ \hat f (n)\} $ are the Fourier coefficients of $f$. Maybe this prof is related to
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k, \ \ \ |x|<1$$
but later I do not know how to continue.

Moreover, putting $L=(I-S)^{-1}$ is it true that $L(e^{i\lambda_n x})=e^{inx}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the concrete problem (Fourier series, ...). What you are using here is just a **Neumann series argument**.

Comment: @PhoemueX, thank you. I've edited my tag.